# Plotstyle one line highlighted

Tags: plotting

Sorry for the stupid question, I am still a total beginner with Mathematica.

I have a list line plot that has some 100-1000 lines (depending on the input). I want my for loop to automatically determine which one of these lines is "important". There are roughly 3 or 4 important lines in there.

So how do I, out of, say, 100 lines which should all show up in different colors, highlight these 3-4 in bold? I don't know beforehand which ones are important -- my for loop will find out. But I cannot write use Plot Style in the standard way {Orange, Thick, Green} because I do not even know at which position the thick line should be.

Do you know what I mean? How do I generalize a position for thick when all others are also colored, but not thick?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You are not a new user on this site. Please include minimal examples of data with your questions. You have also not accepted any answers so far. Selecting an answer makes the Q/A more beneficial for page visitors. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I have had my account for some time, but barely used it. I try to stick to the rules in future as I start to using Mathematica more. Thanks and sorry again.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know beforehand which ones are important -- my for loop will
> find out.

You did not give MWE. I assume you want the important line be marked as say Red, and all the others Gray?
One way, is that as you build the lines, keep track in a list called `importantLines`, the index of the line which is important.

Then build style based on this list to make only those lines in the  `importantLines` red, and everything else say Gray. Something like

```
lines = {x, 2*x, 3 + 4*x, 7*x, 2*x^2 + 5, 7 + x}
importantLines = {2, 5} (*second and fifth lines are important only*)
style = Table[If[MemberQ[importantLines, n], Red, Gray], {n, 1, Length@lines}]
Plot[lines, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> style]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want the others to be dashed, you do

```
lines = {x, 2*x, 3 + 4*x, 7*x, 2*x^2 + 5, 7 + x}
importantLines = {2, 5} (*second and fifth lines are important only*)
style = Table[If[MemberQ[importantLines, n], Red, {Gray, Dashed}], {n, 1, Length@lines}]
Plot[lines, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> style]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

etc... You can customize the style as you want in the above. Make it thick or thin or any other allowed line style.

I am sure there are at least 9 other ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful! How can I mark this answer such that it shows that this problem is solved?

Comment: @Marla to accept an answer at stackexchange, you just click on the little green check/arrow near the top left edge of the answer which you want to accept. You can just look at any accepted answer on this site to see this check marker.